# Array index is out of range error

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm using this code to spawn a random object from an array:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class enemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] enemies; 
    int enemyNo;
    public float maxPos = 6.9f;
    public float delayTimer = 0.75f;
    float timer; 

    void Start () {
        timer = delayTimer;
    }

    void Update () {

        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer <= 0) {

            Vector3 enemyPos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Random.Range (5.0f, -5.5f), transform.position.z);

            //enemyNo = Random.Range (0,8);    
            enemyNo = Random.Range (0, enemies.Length);

            Instantiate (enemies[enemyNo], enemyPos, transform.rotation);
            timer = delayTimer;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I want to do the same thing across different scenes. Each scene has a different amount of objects for the array (set in the inspector), so because they're not all the same I'm getting this error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
```

Is there any way for me to do this differently? Or should I write a new script for each scene?

Comment: Where are you initializing the enemies array?

Comment: @JoaoFSA Unity have an Inspector and there you can initialize public variables.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible in Unity, but can you use a "List<GameObject>" instead of Array?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange An Array is better, because he don't add new objects at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure the `enemies` array has any elements? If it's empty, right now the random number would be `0` and it would try to access that. Maybe there's an extra copy of this component on some gameobject that you didn't fill in the `enemies` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the current length of the array, so you can't get out of the current array range.

```
enemyNo = Random.Range (0, enemies.Length)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried this and the enemies are still spawning as they were but the error is still there. The error is definitely coming from this script, so I'll update my answer to give the full script see if it's coming from something else.

Comment: It should be `enemies.Length -1`, max is inclusive.

Comment: @shadowlif This is what I thought, which is why I thought it must be something else causing the problem. I've gone through the project and removed this script from all game objects, changed the line to enemies.Length then put everything back in its place. I can definitely confirm now that enemies.Length works perfectly. There's a comment further up about leaving the elements at 0, I must have made that mistake in one of the scenes I'm using it in which gave the error. - Removed the above comment to save confusion :)